# We're sorry, but something went wrong (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

Everything works fine on my local server but I'm getting this error message when I try to perform a function after uploading the website into production on `heroku`.

On heroku, everything works fine EXCEPT when a user tries to post a content. It's a simple text form with a post button. I seem to only get this `We're sorry, but something went wrong` error when the # of text exceeds 2 or 3 lines or something. It's a bit random in that everything that is 2 lines or shorter post fine, but when it gets to 2-3 lines, not all go through. When it's over 3, they definitely don't go through.

Anyone know what could be causing this weird error? As I mentioned, all short text posts work just fine but I start getting this error message the longer the text posts get (like exceeding 2 lines in my text box)

Comment: The message you are seeing is the Rails 404 page

Answer (score 5):

Most likely the error is because the field you're trying to input is a `string` field.  Heroku uses `pg` which limits the length of string to 255 characters.  You need to change your model to use `text` fields instead when the input will be long.

You can always look at your logs by doing:

`heroku logs`

and read more information on the error.

Comment: Thanks, do you know if there's an easy way to change the input type for the module from a string to a text? I'm still in the process of learning programming...

Comment: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2799774/rails-migration-for-change-column  Basically you create a migration that will alter the field type from :string to :text.