# ActiveRecord column cannot be cast automatically to type numeric

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, type-conversion

I need to change the data type of a column in a DB from `:string` to `:decimal`. All values are in the following format: `"129.99"`, so converting them should not raise any errors.

To do so I wrote the following migration:

```
def change
  change_column :my_table, :target_column, :decimal
end
```

When I execute this it shows me the following error together with a hint on how to fix it:

```
PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  column "target_column" cannot be cast automatically to type numeric
HINT:  You might need to specify "USING target_column::numeric".
```

However, I can't seem to find any documentation about how to do this, so the hint doesn't really help me.

Whats the best way to perform this migration?

Comment: try ```change_column :my_table, :target_column, 'numeric USING CAST(target_column AS numeric)'```

Comment: @VaoTsun Worked, thx. If you write a proper answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

this should do:

```
def change
  change_column :my_table, :target_column, 'numeric USING CAST(target_column AS numeric)'
end
```

Comment: Note: For future people trying to convert another column with similar issue, remember to enter the `cast` string instead of new_type and replace `numeric` with the new type. If this doesn't work then your data types are too far apart and you may need something similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54313334/10313894

Answer (score 10):

For people just wishing to change the column type and that don't care what happens to the data in that field.

Simply delete the column, and re-create it with the correct type:

```
def change
    remove_column :table_name, :field
    add_column :table_name, :field, :type
end
```