# How to get the total cost and tax percentage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to get the total price which consist of quantity, price, and tax

```
    @order = current_user.orders.build(order_params)
    @order.product = product
    @order.price = product.price
    @orders = product.price * quantity
    @order.total = @orders * 0.029
```

The price and quantity sums up the total but when i add the tax percentage it doesn't calculate at all?

Comment: Does the value to the right of `=` return what you need?, what's not working, if you mean the value isn't getting saved, is because you need to save the object after assigning a new value for an attribute.

Comment: If i add 0.029 it return $0. But if i take 0.029 away it return the corerct price just without the tax

Comment: Is the type of `total` `:float` ?

Comment: total is an integer

Comment: ive updated my code above

Comment: `(24*2*0.02).to_i => 0` you have to change your `total` column type

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2799787/4453714

Answer (score 0):

You get the wrong result, because type of `total` is integer, instead float.

You have to change this column type, so you need to generate new migration:

```
rails g migration change_total_to_be_float_in_orders
```

This generates migration like that:

```
class ChangeTotalToBeFloatInOrders < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
  end
end
```

Add this line to `change` method:

```
change_column :orders, :total, :float
```

Then run the migration:

```
rails db:migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

I have to assume that "total" means that you want to get the total of the order including the tax. Using 0.029 means that you would be getting the tax amount of the order, not the actual

Difference here is

```
25 * 0.029 = 0.725
```

vs

```
25 * 1.029 = 25.725
```

Try this instead.

```
@order.total = @orders * 1.029
```

I tested this based on what you posted, and it worked for me.